# Html tag automatically added textarea value if form submitted through Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

Html tag automatically added textarea value if form submitted through Jquery.

My jquery code.

```
$('#calling').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

In my form one text area is there.

```
<textarea id="area" name="rte1" cols="50" rows="10">Value of textarea.</textarea>
```

Javascript code as below.

```
document.myform.submit();
```

In case of jquery form submit i am getting textarea value in PHP as

```
<p>Value of textarea.</p>
```

But in case of java script form submit i am getting the proper value in php.

Please suggest what is the problem with my jquery code.

Comment: in case of java script what value you are getting in php ?

Comment: in case of java script i am getting "Value of textarea."

Comment: see my answer hope that will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple way in `php` to get the value without any `HTML Tag`

```
$textarea = strip_tags($_REQUEST['rte1']);
```

This will return you `Value of textarea.` without `<p>` tags.

See [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) if you need any more help.

Comment: Yes, this is solved that problem. But my textarea is a html text editor and this disturbed the formatting.

Comment: I didn't get you..Once you have striped out the tags how can they will come again ?

Comment: Actually, textarea is html editor and storing data in DB without html tag and getting back the html tag by using **markdown** script. if i striped then  **markdown** script is not working..

Comment: So waht do you want?? first you asked to remove the automatically generated `p` tag and now ??

Comment: so let them go as it is

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem at all with your jquery code. Tested with POST and GET methods and the server only gets the "Value of textarea." string. You must have something wrong in your PHP.

http://jsfiddle.net/sftHD/

```
document.myform.submit();
$('#myform').submit();
```

Those produce the same result.

Comment: My php code getting value through $_POST['rte1'] and this value i am storing in DB.